# How do I send one of two file names dependent on the date the python script is run?

Tags: python, datetime

I have an excel file that is created on Tuesday and Friday.  When it runs on Tuesday it has data from the previous Thursday thru Sunday.  When it runs on Friday it has data from the previous Monday thru Wednesday.

When I send the file I like to tag the date range in the subject line of the email.
Example:  If today is Tuesday 10/27/2020 then the subject line would read "Data 20201022 - 20201025" (4 days of data)
If today is Friday 10/30/2020 then the subject line would read "Data 20201026 - 20201028" (3 days of data)

In a nutshell here is what my logic was but I'm not sure how to code or format it correctly.  The only part I'm needing help with is the IF logic.  If today is Tuesday send this file name or if today is Friday send the other file name.  All the other parts of my script are good.  This is just a snippet and an example.

```
dt = (datetime.date.today()).strftime("%A")
dte = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=2)).strftime('%Y%m%d')
dte1 = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=5)).strftime('%Y%m%d')
dte2 = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=4)).strftime('%Y%m%d')

if dt = "Tuesday"
emailreport.send(subject=f'Product Data {dte1} - {dte}',attch=output,distro_nm='name_list')

if dt = "Friday"
emailreport.send(subject=f'Product Data {dte2} - {dte}',attch=output,distro_nm='name_list')
```

I'm fairly new to Python so this may not be the best way to do it or even possible.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Have you tried writing pseudocode? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: your code seems fine in principle; some nit-picking, you can reduce the calls to datetime.now to one, e.g. `now = datetime.now()` and derive dte etc. from that, and your if-statements should look something like `if now.weekday() == 1: # = "Tuesday"`

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object list with a range of 7 numbers for the day of the week

```
    mylist = list(range(7)) # days of week`
    def myfunc(obj):
       for elem in mylist:
          if elem >=3:
              print('x') # Friday (mon thru Wednesday)
          elif elem <3: 
              print('y') # Tuesday (Thursday thru Sunday)

    # then call function
    myfunc(mylist)
```

the function call will print out x and y depending on conditions met.

This is more of a pseudocode example, you will  likely need to change much of your code around but this is the basic logic that could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you write a piece of code or df to get an example.

I think you can use functions like:

```
df.dayofweek ==1 # Tuesday

df.dayofweek ==4 # Friday
```

Thank you